# How to transform Markdown query to Strapi query on GraphiQL?

Tags: graphql, markdown, gatsby, content-type, strapi

I'm trying to get my hands on **Gatsby + Strapi** development (adding Material for styling), I'm new to both Gatsby and Strapi although I have some basic knowledge of React and it's making the way easier to follow.
I'm using this **Gatsby Starter**: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/Vagr9K/gatsby-material-starter/ which includes the Material design I'm trying to achieve, but I'm having some trouble changing the **Markdown queries to Strapi queries** to avoid making a lot of code changes (posts are exactly the same but stored in Strapi). I have three Content Types in Strapi corresponding to the three different pages the original starter provides: *Post*, *Category*, and *Tag*.

This is the original MarkdownRemark graphQL query included in the *post.jsx* template:

```
query BlogPostBySlug($slug: String!) {
  markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
    html
    timeToRead
    excerpt
    frontmatter {
      title
      cover
      date
      category
      tags
    }
    fields {
      slug
      date
    }
  }
}
```

How can I change it to retrieve the same info from Strapi?
I'm really new to this Strapi world so I'm having a lot of doubts with the GraphQL, as I can't follow the guide from the Markdown query because the Information displayed is not the same.

I'm also having trouble differentiating between allStrapiArticles and StrapiArticle, what's the main purpose of those?

EDIT: I've been testing the existing queries on **GraphiQL** to check what they are returning and this is what I'm seeing:

For the *tag.jsx* query:

```
query TagPage($tag: String) {
  allMarkdownRemark(
    limit: 1000
    sort: { fields: [fields___date], order: DESC }
    filter: { frontmatter: { tags: { in: [$tag] } } }
  ) {
    totalCount
    edges {
      node {
        fields {
          slug
          date
        }
        excerpt
        timeToRead
        frontmatter {
          title
          tags
          cover
          date
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

GraphiQL returns nothing:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMarkdownRemark": {
      "totalCount": 0,
      "edges": []
    }
  }
}
```

For the *category.jsx* query:

```
query CategoryPage($category: String) {
  allMarkdownRemark(
    limit: 1000
    sort: { fields: [fields___date], order: DESC }
    filter: { frontmatter: { category: { eq: $category } } }
  ) {
    totalCount
    edges {
      node {
        fields {
          slug
          date
        }
        excerpt
        timeToRead
        frontmatter {
          title
          tags
          cover
          date
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, everything works fine and it retrieves article data.

And for the case of the query I've added as an example in this post (upper part of the question) I'm getting the following error:

```
 "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable \"$slug\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided."
    ...
```

Comment: I'm testing the existing GraphQL queries for Markdown Content on GraphiQL and I keep getting errors, for the query included in the question I'm getting: `"message": "Variable \"$slug\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided."`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are passing your variable in through Query Variables at the bottom of GraphiQL.

[image]

---

First, I would query AllMarkdownRemark to make sure you're getting the nodes from Gatsby. Something like:

```
query MyQuery {
  allMarkdownRemark {
    edges {
      node {
        fields {
          slug
        }
        frontmatter {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If the `slug` is showing up, then this should work:

[image]

Sometimes a slug is not being generated. Which should show up checking allMarkdownRemark.

Comment: That solved the error but I'm not getting anything anyway: `{
  "data": {
    "markdownRemark": null
  }
}`

Comment: The query that gave me the error is called *BlogPostBySlug* and it doesn't have a filter